# How to add Explode or Explode-like animation/transition in android versions below 5.0?

Tags: android, android-animation, android-transitions

I'm developing a material design app & I've declared the `Explode` animation to be the `exitTransition` of my activities.

I want the same animation in **android versions below `5.0`**, but the problem is that it is available only in **android version 5.0** & above.

I really don't know how to do this?

Please let me know.

Sorry for bad formatting of the question!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: well as you said, that exit animation only exists in 5.0+

Comment: @tyczj thanks for telling me. But, how can I add Explode or Explode-like animation/transitions as activity transition in android version below 5.0?

Comment: [this](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/transitions/overview.html) can be of help, to simplify, apply a custom transition and play an image animation